# How to hide horizontal range lines on AndroidPlot's XYPlot?

Tags: android, androidplot

I'd like to remove the horizontal lines from this XYPlot chart:

[image]

I've already tried doing this:

```
plot.getGraph().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

and added this in the XYPlot's xml description:

```
ap:rangeLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"
```

Comment: I just tested `ap:domainLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"` and `ap:rangeLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"` and both are working.

Comment: I solved my problem by removing the line plot.setLinesPerRangeLabel(5); For some reason, this line forces range grid lines to be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to call those two methods (to remove both background lines), if you need to remove only the horizontal ones just call the second one.

```
//this removes the vertical lines
plot.getGraph().setDomainGridLinePaint(null)

//this removes the horizontal lines
plot.getGraph().setRangeGridLinePaint(null)
```

> PS: Obviously you can pass as parameter something different than `null` to get different results. For example you can pass a custom `Paint` object based on your needs.

This is the result with both set to `null`:

[image: XYZ Plot without the background grid]

Comment: Good answer, but make sure you don't call plot.setLinesPerRangeLabel(5);